# Looping through JSON data in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have some JSON data being returned from an AJAX call. I then need to parse this data in javascript.

The data looks like so:

```
[
 {
 "id": "23",
 "date_created": "2016-05-12 14:52:42"
},
{
 "id": "25",
 "date_created": "2016-05-12 14:52:42"
}
]
```

Why is it when i run this code on the data that i get multiple undefined's?
(var json being the variable holding my json data)

```
 for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     var obj = json[i];

     console.log(obj.id);
  }
```

However if i assign the json directly to the variable like so:

```
var json = [
 {
 "id": "23",
 "date_created": "2016-05-12 14:52:42"
},
{
 "id": "25",
 "date_created": "2016-05-12 14:52:42"
}
];
```

Then it works fine!

Any ideas guys? Thanks

Comment: Where is `json` getting a value from?

Comment: Where do you declare json? How do you assign `var json` the returned json data?

Comment: Make sure the `JSON` you're getting is not stringified JSON. In that case do `JSON.parse(json_string)` and then loop and more ...

Comment: Spot on Prashant! Thanks guy!

Comment: json isn't being set correctly. Chrome offers some pretty legit tools for debugging. Set a breakpoint in the Sources tab of the dev tools and see what the actual value is at runtime.

Comment: @Ryan been thru that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `JSON` you're getting is not just stringified `JSON`. In that case do `JSON.parse(json_string)` and then loop and more processing.

**Example:**

```
var string_json = '[{"a":1},{"b":2}]'; // may be your API response is like this
var real_json = JSON.parse(string_json); // real_json contains actual objects
console.log(real_json[0].a, real_json[1].b); // logs 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `JSON` that, you are using.

- It's an object array.
- When you get `JSON`, parse that JSON using method `JSON.parse`.
- Assign this JSON to a variable and then use iteration over it...

Ex:

```
 var json ='[{"id": "23","date_created": "2016-05-12 14:52:42"},{"id": "25","date_created": "2016-05-12 14:52:42"}]';
 var parsedJson = JSON.parse(json);
 for(var i = 0; i < parsedJson.length; i++) {
     var obj = parsedJson[i];

     console.log(obj.id);
  }
```